# Internel service error while scraping with beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use the following code for scraping some movies' genres in a loop by iterating through their urls.

```
import random
import time
import csv
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import reader

values=[]
with open('mubi_movie_data.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    # pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    # Iterate over each row in the csv using reader object
    for row in csv_reader:
        # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv
        url = row[3]
        if url == 'movie_url':
            continue
        else:
            print(url)
            r: requests.Response = requests.get(url)
            soup: bs4.BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
            for soup in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "css-1wuve65 eyplj6810"}):
                    print(soup)
                    print(type(soup))
                    # Parse company name.
                    name = soup.text
                    values.append(name)

thecsv = csv.writer(open("your.csv", 'wb'))
for value in values:
    thecsv.writerow(value)
```

For the first 10 or 15 scrapes, everything went fine. Then the website blocks my access to it and stopped me from scraping and gave me internal service error when I try to reload the page. I have done some search that I have to change the user agent to fix this but do not know how to do it with python. I am completely new to web scraping. Anyone can help?

Comment: URL of the website pls?

Comment: It's the movie urls, not just one url. The base url is https://mubi.com/films/, which is followed by many other movies. eg. https://mubi.com/films/la-promesse